# Execution cycle of sed s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/g

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Why does `echo ,,, |sed s':\(,\)\(,\):\1*\2:'g` yield "`,*,,`" rather than "`,*,*,`"?  In other words: why, despite the "g" flag, does sed not insert '`*`' between one pair of commas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because with the two `,`s in `(,\)\(,\)`, you have already matched the first two `,`s and the Regex pattern matched so far won't backtrack for the rest of the line. Only one is left now that is the last `,` hence it just printed as it is without any `*` in between it the second last one.

If you have another `,` in input, you would get the desired (global, `g`) response:

```
% echo ,,,, | sed s':\(,\)\(,\):\1*\2:'g
,*,,*,
```

Comment: What's with the weird quotation? (Why leave `s` and `g` out of the quote marks?)

Comment: @GnP Haha, that's inherited from the OP.

Comment: or `echo ,,,,, |sed s':\(,\)\(,\):\1*:’g`

Answer (score 8):

The why of the question been already [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308294/109046) by @heemayl

Workaround with `sed` (here assuming GNU `sed`) - loop recursively as long as a match is found

```
$ echo ,,, | sed -E ':a s/(,)(,)/\1*\2/ ; ta'
,*,*,

$ echo ,,,, | sed -E ':a s/(,)(,)/\1*\2/ ; ta'
,*,*,*,
```

POSIXly:

```
$ echo ,,,, | sed -e :a -e 's/\(,\)\(,\)/\1*\2/; ta'
,*,*,*,
```

Or with `perl`

```
$ echo ,,, | perl -pe 's/,\K(?=,)/*/g'
,*,*,

$ echo ,,,, | perl -pe 's/,\K(?=,)/*/g'
,*,*,*,
```